# jhbuild build: unknown repository type arch

Tags: gstreamer, jhbuild

Hi i am trying to use ***JHBuild script*** for ***GStreamer*** build setup, i followed the steps given in wiki @ http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/GStreamer_using_jhbuild 
But when i give the command **gst-jhbuild build** , its giving *jhbuild build: unknown repository type arch* , which is there in gstreamer.modules file. How can i solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Try adding module_autogenargs['gstreamer'] += '--with-arch=<cpu>' in jhbuildrc file.